# Moving an element from one area to another with javascript vs jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change something from jquery over to pure javascript, but I cannot for the life of me get it to work. This is the code:

```
var test = document.getElementById("one");
var test2 = document.getElementById("two");
 test2.append(test.getElementsByTagName("h1"))
// $("#two").append(test.getElementsByTagName("h1"))
```

if I use the commented out section with jQuery, it works just fine. Any help would be appreciated!

[myJSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silverstarfy/18hxf35h/)

Comment: Well for one, `append` is not a JavaScript DOM method. Try googling "javascript append element", or read the jQuery source code for the `append()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You must use `appendChild()` dom method

```js
var test = document.getElementById("one");
var test2 = document.getElementById("two");
test2.appendChild(test.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0]);
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <h1>1.h1 from id=one</h1>
  <h1>2.h1 from id=one</h1>
</div>
<div id="two">
  <h3>here id=two element starts</he>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use appendChild instead of append and select the first h1 in collection:

```
test2.appendChild(test.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0])
```